# Openshift vs. Cloudfoundry Container-Container routing

Tags: routes, openshift, cloud-foundry

In Cloud-foundry it is possible to directly target a specific container by using "1.myname.apps.internal" and "2.myname.apps.internal" hostnames etc.

I could not find anything alike on Openshift. Is there anything similar available on Openshift?

Comment: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/networking/understanding-networking.html#nw-ne-openshift-dns_understanding-networking

Answer (score 0):

Your target should not be a Pod, but typically a Service that will forward traffic to Pods. This will allow you to scale Pods later on without changing any DNS names or similar.

In OpenShift (=Kubernetes), all Services receive a DNS name under `.svc.cluster.local`, typically like this:

```
<service_name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

So if you have a Service that is called "backend" in the namespace "myapp-prod", you can talk to that Service using the following name:

```
backend.myapp-prod.svc.cluster.local
```

Within a namespace you should be able to talk to your service directly using `backend` without having to specify the complete name. You can find more information in the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).